# Does regularization penalize models that are simpler than needed?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling, regularization

Yes, regularization penalizes models that are  more complex than needed. But does it also penalize models that are simpler than needed?

Comment: Given we use an appropriate testing procedure to select our regularisation parameter strength, it *should not* penalise any models unnecessarily. (+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For regularization terms similar to $\left\|\theta\right\|_2^2$ in effect, no they don't, they only push toward simplicity, i.e. parameters closer to zero.

Error terms such as $\sum_i \left\|y_i - f_{\theta}(x_i)\right\|_2^2$ are responsible for fighting back toward complexity (penalizing over-simplification), since the simplest model, i.e. $\theta = 0$, leads to a high error.

We balance these two forces by using a regularization parameter ($\lambda$) in a summation like
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \left\|y_i - f_{\theta}(x_i)\right\|_2^2 + \lambda\left\|\theta\right\|_2^2,$$
where higher $\lambda$ forces the model toward more simplicity.

Comment: So, regularization like L2, L1 correspond to the first case, right?

Comment: @alienflow yes they all force toward zero (most simple).